# MySQL Accounting Code Database Structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question on making the effective database structure for accounting code. The result I was expecting is this

```
| ID | Code |          Name           | Parent |
| 1  |  1   |         Assets          |        |
| 2  |  1   |  Tangible Fixed Assets  |   1    |
| 3  |  1   |         Building        |   2    |
| 4  |  2   |  Intangible Fixed Assets|   1    |
| 5  |  1   |        CopyRights       |   3    |
```

I've been thinking about making 3 tables such as **tbl_lvl1** for main parent, **tbl_lvl2** as first child and **tbl_lvl3** as second child. I found about recursive query, which is just only using 1 table, but it's kind of difficult making recursive query in MYSQL.
And the result I want to view in PHP, is something like this

```
|  Code  |        Name              |
|   1    | Assets                   |
|   11   |   Tangible Fixed Assets  |
|   111  |      Building            |
|   12   |   Intangible Fixed Asset |
|   121  |      CopyRights          |
```

Which structure I should make? Using 3 table or 1 table ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a search tree, and I'd especially suggest a [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

A search tree, generally spoken, allows you to hierarchically search for all sub-nodes in a single query through nested intervals.

There are literally dozens of implementations, so you don't need to dig deep into the details, even though I would suggest it, as it's a major data structure that you should be used to.

Comment: it took days for me to understand B-tree,but your suggestion provides me answer,thanks @ravenixx